# Remix error when deploying with wei value

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I get the following error every time I try to deploy a program with a wei value greater than zero:

Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract testContract {

    uint value;

    constructor (uint _p) public {
        value = _p;
    }

    function setP(uint _n) payable public {
        value = _n;
    }

    function setNP(uint _n) public {
        value = _n;
    }

    function get () view public returns (uint) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
creation of testContract errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.

creation of testContract pending...

0 [vm] from: OxAb8...35cb2 to: testContract.(constructor) value: 1 wei data: 0x608...00001 logs: 0 hash: 0x344...07156

creation of testContract errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question isn't really searchable at all. Sharing just screenshots doesn't help finding your question and makes it really hard to help out. Could you please add the exact error you're facing?

Stackoverflow should be treated as a growing source of searchable problems and solutions, like living documentation for all code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to specify a "payable" specifier in the smart contract constructor - like for "setP" function.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are sending Wei with the contract deployment transaction which is not required.

The transaction can get reverted because of the following reasons:

- Transaction done is not for a payable function
- The amount you are sending is less than you current balance